# Peculiar Non-Existing Element Space in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a layout that should be fairly straightforward, but for some unknown reason there is just this magical space appearing from ...... nothing. There is no element for it. I can't explain it.

I have a picture, and a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem. This happens across all browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/qSQ7b/

[image: Picture]

Comment: It's surely something with the margins. If you put `* {margin:0}` it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's coming from the `p` element in here:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <article>
        <p>
            This information is appearing below a strange white bar that really shouldn't be there...
        </p>
    </article>
</div>
```

You're getting bitten by collapsing margins:

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins
- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

To fix it, you could add `overflow: hidden` to your `article`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qSQ7b/3/

Comment: Agreed. Try to remove the margins.

Comment: I am so lost. Is this really intended to be considered a **feature**? The way people are commenting on the first site you linked makes it sound like this is a 'good' thing. This seems like a horrible flaw!

Comment: Removing the `margin`s from the `p` will work, but you generally do want `p` elements to have some `margins`. That's why I'm suggesting "fixing" the collapsing margins.

Comment: @Ciel: Believe it or not, it *is* useful. The last paragraph from the Sitepoint article sums it up nicely: "Although the margin collapse behavior is at first a little unintuitive, it does make life easier in the case of multiple nested elements, where the behavior is often desirable. As shown above, easy methods are available to help you stop the collapse if required."

Comment: Won't setting the `overflow: hidden` cause other problems with the way the `<article>` will get sized, though?

Comment: @Ciel: Unlikely. The only way it could cause a problem is if you were trying to position elements inside your `article` outside of your `article`. It won't affect the width or height.

Comment: Since this will obviously be a re-occuring problem, I am going to use ... `#content-area .container *:first-child { overflow: hidden; }` to just do this to the first element after the `div.content` of the body of the page. Will that suffice? Or is there some hidden caveat I should know about for that?

Comment: @Ciel - If you don't set an explicit height, it generally shouldn't, but will actually resize based on its contents. It's another thing that sounds unintuitive, but you run into it a lot if you use a lot of floats (`overflow:hidden` on an unsized parent container with child floats will clear the floats in most cases, and the parent container will resize to fit the contents, instead of collapsing into nothingness).

Comment: I actually thought it worked the other way around. In the past, in order to get things to force the parent container to expand along with them, I had to set it to `overflow: auto`. Setting it to `overflow: hidden` always resulted in the height being `0` so if I needed to add any kind of styling to a container element, it would fail. So now I am a bit confused.

Comment: @Ciel: `#content-area .container *:first-child { overflow: hidden; }` looks fine to me. For both preventing collapsing margins *and* clearing floats, both `overflow: hidden` and `overflow: auto` will work the same way. `hidden` is preferred because with `auto`, you can sometimes get scrollbars which look incredibly ugly.

Comment: So `auto` just defaults to `hidden` unless a parent has something specified otherwise that it inherits down in the DOM tree?

Comment: @Ciel: No, that's not it. The property `overflow` defaults to `visible`. Also, `overflow` is not an inheritable property. Think of `auto` and `hidden` as doing exactly the same thing, except `hidden` will hide content, whereas `auto` will provide scrollbars to show the content. It's just that setting `overflow` to anything other than the default of `visible` has a lot of side effects, such as clearing floats and stopping collapsing margins.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at it in your favorite browser's developer tools (such as Firefox's Firebug), you'll see it's the default margin that's doing it. Set your div's padding to 1em and it should go away.

Or your could also set `p {margin:0}`, but that will remove the margins from all `<p>` tags, which might not be desired.

Comment: Just the parent div, or the `<article>`, whichever has the background color.

Comment: Setting `padding: 1px` (or `padding: whatever`) works because it stops margin collapsing. Here's the jsFiddle from my answer, with `overflow: hidden` replaced by `padding: 1px`: http://jsfiddle.net/qSQ7b/4/

Comment: @thirtydot - Hah, I never thought of doing it that way. I always just set the padding to equal the margin of the guilty element, which has always worked for me. I knew about margin collapsing, but assumed it only worked when the two elements were the same (such as two adjacent `<p>` tags).